# Why isn't my Tkinter button image updating?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

You may recognize this code. I'm steadily improving it :)
This time I'm stuck trying to figure out why a button image will not update after I click on it. I'm not getting any errors, so I'm not sure how to debug this.

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog,filedialog,colorchooser,messagebox,Frame,Button
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()

load1 = Image.open("example.jpg")
root.render1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load1)

canv_1 = tk.Canvas(root, bg="gray")
canv_1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
canv_1.grid_columnconfigure(6, weight=2)

canv_1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")
canv_1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="news")

labels = ["Image", "Chapter #", "Chapter Title", "Step", "Slide", "Sequence Step", "Instructions"]
root.label_wid = []
font1 = ("arial", 15, "bold")
for i in range(len(labels)):
    root.label_wid.append(tk.Label(canv_1, font=font1, relief="raised", text=labels[i]).grid(row=0, column=i,
                                                                                                        sticky="we"))
def exportCode():
    print("code exported")
    a = instruction_col[0].get('1.0','10.0')
    print(a)
    print("end")


root.images = [
    ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("example.jpg"))
    for y in range(1,6)
]

def change_img(y):
    #print(y)
    #print(len(root.images))
    root.img1 = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    root.load_img1 = Image.open(root.img1)
    root.render_img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(root.load_img1)
    image_col[y]['image'] = root.render_img1
    print(image_col[y]['image'])
    print(image_col[y-1]['image'])
    print(root.render_img1)

c1 = "#a9d08e"
c2 = "#8dd1bf"

image_col = [
    tk.Button(
        canv_1,
        image=root.render1,
        relief="raised",
        bg="light gray",
        command = lambda: change_img(y),
    )
    for y in range(0, 5)
]

for y, image_cell in enumerate(image_col, 1):
    image_cell.grid(row=y, column=0, sticky='news')

instruction_col = [
    tk.Text(
        canv_1,
        bg="white",
        wrap="word",
        font=("arial",15), width=20, height=10)
    for y in range(0, 5)
]

for y, image_cell in enumerate(instruction_col, 1):
    image_cell.grid(row=y, column=6, sticky='news')
# ================================================================================================

bt1 = tk.Button(canv_1, text="Export", font=font1, command=exportCode).grid(row=0, column=7)
load2 = Image.open("scroll-up.png")
root.render2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load2)
load3 = Image.open("scroll-down.png")
root.render3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load3)
scroll_up = tk.Button(canv_1, image=root.render2).grid(row=1, column=7, rowspan=2)  # , sticky="n")
scroll_up = tk.Button(canv_1, image=root.render3).grid(row=3, column=7, rowspan=2)  # , sticky="s")

root.mainloop()
```

It was working fine before when I wasn't using a list, and I manually defined each widget as RxCx (Row #, Column #) but now that I simplified my code with lists `image_col` & `instruction_col`, I'm having trouble with the `change_image(y)` function

Below is the function I was previously using:

*it worked fine, but I took up a lot of lines manually defining each widget*

```
def change_img(row):
    if row == 1:
        root.img1 = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        root.load_img1 = Image.open(root.img1)
        root.render_img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(root.load_img1)
        R1C0['image']=root.render_img1
    if row == 2:
# etc...
```

Comment: @BryanOakley, I'm not sure what you mean. It works fine for me. For instance, if I type this into the console: `for y in range(1,6): print(y)` I get `1 2 3 4 5` And likewise this code does iterate and create 5x widgets for me. I changed it to range(0,5) for consistency.

Comment: `lambda: change_img(y)` calls the function with the value of `y` at the time the `lambda` is called, NOT the time it was defined.  Since `y` was a loop variable, and the loop has long since finished before any Button can possibly invoke this lambda, they're all doing `change_img(5)` (5 being the final value of `y`).  Solution: `lambda y=y: change_img(y)`, which captures the value at the time of definition.

Comment: My apologies. I didn't realize it was a list comprehension.